# How to make admin page of django do this particular thing?

Tags: python, django

I am using the django admin page to put questions into the database.

My models.py is this:

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question_name


class PythonQuestion(models.Model):
    question_no = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    question_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    question_testcase = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    question_difflevel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I want these particular changes to my django-admin page:-

1. As of now, when I am able to add the contents to both the Question model and PythonQuestion model from the admin page. What I want is that I should be able to write into the Question model and then be directed to a page where I can write data into the PythonQuestion model. My pages are up and running; all I need is the directing of links.
2. I want to upload the answers to each questions which are in some file format(Doesn't matter which format here.Lets assume a text file). How do I do that in the admin page?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using an inheritence approach where PythonQuestion is a subclass of Question? Have you got an answer model to link to the questions?

Comment: No. I don't. Is it a better idea to use inheritance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually I think it might be. You can [read more about it in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) but essentially Django has 3 types of inheritence; **abstract, multitable and proxy** which are all useful in different situations:

- abstract inheritance is useful when your base class will never need to be instantiated itself (i.e. the base model has no table but it's children all have tables)
- multitable inheritance is useful when you have a base model that is useful in itself but can be extended (i.e. the base model has a table and it's children all have tables)
- proxy is useful when you want to extend only the functionality of a parent model (i.e. the base model has a table but it's children don't have tables)

and a quick example (multi table):

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.CharField(...)

class Question(models.Model):
    """What all questions have in common"""
    title = models.CharField(...)
    text = models.CharField(...)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)

class PythonQuestion(Question):
    """What specifics a python question might have"""
    python_version = models.CharField(...)
```

You will be able to enter all the data in one go in the django admin (this is the same for both multitable and abstract inheritence). Furthremore, You have an answer attached to every question. These answers can be uploaded via fixtures if needs be (or manually entered through the admin)

Comment: Thank you for this reply! Clears a lot of doubts. Though my problem here is this - I want to go to PythonQuestion page right after Question page. Rather than coming back to the admin index page and going from there again. I hope you are getting me.

Comment: Because you are using inheritence, you will never go to the Question page on its own, as everything that it has (title, text, answer) will show up in the PythonQuestion page when using the admin.